# Code not executing a function which tells to find a number that is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 10

Tags: javascript, html

So I was trying to write a function in java Script in which it finds a number that is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 10, which is 2520 btw. can someone help me?

```js
var num;
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000)
  if((num%1===0)&&(num%2===0)&&(num%3===0)&&(num%4===0)&&(num%5===0)&&(num%6===0)&&(num%7===0)&&(num%8===0)&&(num%9===0)&&(num%10===0)){
       console.log(num)
  }
}
findDiv();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? You're getting a number between 1 and 4000 and in case its what you want, print it. Else do nothing. What did you try to actually do with that logic?

Answer (score 1):

## What your function Doing is

```js
var num;
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);
 // Find a random number between 0 to 4000
  if((num%1===0)&&(num%2===0)&&(num%3===0)&&(num%4===0)&&(num%5===0)&&(num%6===0)&&(num%7===0)&&(num%8===0)&&(num%9===0)&&(num%10===0)){
       console.log(num);
       // if that number is 0 or 2520 console log that element
       // Now function end
  }
  // check if it is creating a number or not
  console.log("Number is " + num)
}
// Now calling the findDiv() for one time 
findDiv();
```

## What you want

To find the number 2520

To achieve this you have to call the function until it reruns 2520 .
You also have to add condition for checking of `num !==0`

You can achieve that by recursion .

```js
var num;
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000)
  if((num!==0)&&(num%1===0)&&(num%2===0)&&(num%3===0)&&(num%4===0)&&(num%5===0)&&(num%6===0)&&(num%7===0)&&(num%8===0)&&(num%9===0)&&(num%10===0)){
      console.log("product num");
       console.log(num)
  }else{
    findDiv();
  }
  // console.log('initial num');
  // console.log(num);
}
findDiv();
```

### If u have performance concern then stay with me

## What the above function is doing

creation a random number between 0 to 4000 when the function `findDiv()` is calling and then further checks for validation.

The catch is

```
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);
// suppose num is 4

... 
}
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);
// again num is 4

... 
}
function findDiv(){
 num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);
// once again num is 4

... 
}
```

as you can see we are calling `findDiv()` three times per same number as `Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);` generating a number which could be any thing.

## So how to eliminate this multime calling function

we can create a range and check for one by one

```js
var num;
function findDiv(num){
 // num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000)
  if((num%1===0)&&(num%2===0)&&(num%3===0)&&(num%4===0)&&(num%5===0)&&(num%6===0)&&(num%7===0)&&(num%8===0)&&(num%9===0)&&(num%10===0)){
      console.log("product num");
       console.log(num);
  }

}

const min = 1 ; // we don't want zero to be our answer
const max = 4000 ;
for (let i = min; i < max ; i++) {
 findDiv(i);
}
```

#### But again problem is for loop is running 4000 times while it should stop at 2520 lets eliminate this :-

```js
var num;
function findDiv(num){
 // num= Math.floor(Math.random()*4000);
  let finalObject = {
    found:false,
    num: null,
  }
  if((num%1===0)&&(num%2===0)&&(num%3===0)&&(num%4===0)&&(num%5===0)&&(num%6===0)&&(num%7===0)&&(num%8===0)&&(num%9===0)&&(num%10===0)){
    // matched the return number and set found to true
      finalObject = {
       found:true,
       number: num,
     }
  }
  return finalObject ;

}

const min = 1 ; // we don't want zero to be our answer
const max = 4000 ;
for (let i = min; i < max ; i++) {
 let ans = findDiv(i) ;
 // Now store the returned value in ans variable
  if(ans.found){
  // if ans.found is true then console the number within it
  console.log(ans.number)
  // now stop the loop
  break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function smallestDiv(num) {
    const BASE = num;

    for (let i = 1; i <= BASE; i++) {
        if (num % i !== 0) {
            num += BASE;
            i = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

console.log(smallestDiv(10)) // 2520
```